# exec() function doesn't rule svn checkout

Tags: php, svn, exec

I'm writing some functions in php using exec() to interrogate a svn.

```
The commands exec("svn list ".$myurl) works.
```

Now, I try to get a path on a svn repository with the checkout command.
When I put the command "svn checkout http://core.wordress.org/tags/2.9.2/ last-version" directly in the console, it works.

But when I do this from a php script using exec(), like this :

```
exec("svn checkout ".$myurl, $dir)
```

it doesn't work.

Have you an idea ??

Comment: Check permissions to where you're trying to write the checked out copy? The PHP script might be running as some other user than your shell, and thus lacking write permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can have a variety of reasons.

- The user PHP runs under is not allowed to write into the directory you want to check out into
- The SVN repository requires login credentials that are not cached for the user PHP runs under
- The SVN checkout process starts, but requires some additional input like the dreaded "Do you want to accept this certificate" with unsigned certificates.

Try adding `2>&1` to the command to redirect stderr to stdout, and take a look at `$dir`. Also make use of the `$return_var` parameter to [exec()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

And as Jacob pointed out, always use `escapeshellargs()` for your command arguments.

Comment: Thanks for answers.
I think that PHP user is not allowed to write into a directory.

You know how to fix it ??

Comment: @bahamut if you have access to the server, you can change the directory permissions. If not, you can try to do a `chmod 777` on the directory in your FTP client - just note that this makes the directory writable for everybody on the server.

Comment: `chmod 777 your/directory/that/you/want/to/do/the/checkout/in`